# Java save json byte array image to particular location

Tags: json, java

I have one application that posts json data like below

```
{
    "image": "data:image/png;base64,eAvQPaQEJCABCUjg/wNeEta73J3yXwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==................"
}
```

It posts image(png or jpg) base64 byte array in the "image" key.

I want to save that image under the name "datetime.png" into my specified location.
For this I am using the code below:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Path("/getImage")
public Response GetImage(String json) {
    java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
    JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();

    try {
        JSONObject innerJsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        String imageCode=innerJsonObj.getString("image");
        String base64Image = imageCode.split(",")[1];
        byte[] imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Image);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\image\\" + currentTime + ".png");
        try {
            fos.write(imageBytes);
        } finally {
            fos.close();
        }

        returnJson.put("success", true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSONObject errorJson = new JSONObject();
        errorJson.put("success", false);
        return Response.ok(errorJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }

    return Response.ok(returnJson.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
}
```

But it gives me the following Error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\image\2016-07-15 17:04:34.png (The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: The colon ':' is not valid in a file name on Windows, since it is used for drive selection. Are you on Windows?

Comment: @tobi6 yes i am on windows. I have one D drive, in that drive i already created one folder with name "image" and i want to save image on this folder.

Comment: @tobi6 in future i have to deploy this service on Ubuntu tomcat server. So please give me solution that is compatible with both windows and ubuntu also.

Comment: Try creating the filename without colons.

Comment: @tobi6 you means ""D\\image\\" + currentTime + ".png""

Comment: SimpleDateFormat should *not* use colons, e.g. `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss"). I am not sure if the syntax is correct but this should give you an idea.

Comment: @tobi6 yes you right. image successfully created on "D:\image\" but currently its not dynamic because i am using static path. So how can i do this dynamic. When i deploy this on Ubuntu tomcat server i don't have to change any code?

Comment: You should read up for example about Java properties files.